# Javascript Event Listener on Text Field

Tags: javascript, events, listener

I have a text input on a form that I need to check if the value has changed at anytime.  Essentially the text input is a date field and I'm using a 3rd parties script to popup a calendar where you can select a date which is then set as the text field value.

So here is my problem.  Say when the form is loaded the text field already has a value of 1/1/11 if someone clicks on the field and changes it with the keyboard to 1/2/11 or anything else my event listener kicks off and executes the function I want.  My problem is that if someone clicks the calendar icon and selects a date though it changes the value of the input field it doesn't kick off the event handler.

I've tried using onchange event handler directly on the input box and an event listener for the input box and it appears both only pick up the change when focus on the field has changed.  Here is the event listener script the way it sits now..

```
document.getElementById('anchor1x').addEventListener('change', function() {
   alert("date changed");
}, false);
```

Is there something else I can do to check if the field value is changed be it by user input through direct typing or through the calendar select?

Comment: Which third-party script is doing the date picker popup?

Comment: The calendar widget probably lets you pass in a callback to be executed when a date is selected.

Comment: This is the calendar popup I'm using: http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/calendarpopup/ 

The only action I can see it takes is an onmouseup action which closes the calendar popup after a date is selected.  My first thought was to add my script on this same action but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps add an event listener to the icon as well?  That way when its selected, it'll also fire.

Comment: The icon works with an onclick event which loads the calendar into a div.  I can't run my event in the same onclick because it needs to wait for the calendar day to be selected and it does not.  I tried using onblur but apparently an image doesn't have focus when you click on it, just when you tab through.

Comment: @Larry Why not try using jQuery.  I'm not sure if JS has an equivalent function, but the .live() function from jQuery might prove useful here:

http://api.jquery.com/live/

It essentially goes one step farther, allowing elements introduced at a later date to trigger the function.